# Cannot get proper return data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What is wrong:

```
$('#btnSend').click(function()
{     
    var msg = $('#txtar').val();  // textarea
    alert (msg); // works well, for example 'abc'
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "write.php",
        data: {msg: msg},
        success: function(r)
        {
            alert(r); // doesn't work
        }
    });
});
```

`write.php`:

```
$a = $_POST['msg'];
echo $a;
```

Instead of `abc` I get the content of whole `write.php` file in the alert.

Comment: show me the whole code of write.php...maybe you are missing the <?php and the ?>

Comment: check console for error, and particulary the network tab. You could use error callback of ajax method, this will provide you error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `write.php` contain opening and closing php tags:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['msg'];
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: Mamma Mia !   Solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Thats very simple...

write.php

```
 $a = $_POST['msg'];
 echo $a;
 exit;
```

put exit or end here or else the code will move further unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your `write.php` file does not contain `<?php`. Add it at the beginnig. The closing `?>` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
alert(r.msg);
```

or

```
alert(r->msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

- php5 doesn't need closing php tags if its a file with **only** php

Also here's a small example. Just tested this on an apache2.4 server with libapache2-mod-php5. If PHP code works otherwise though, don't worry about your server, or the config, just make sure you're including a JS library to make those AJAX requests work.

PHP(5)

```
<?php
if($_POST && isset($_POST['payload'])) {
     echo "hello ".$_POST['payload'];
}
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "this.php",
    data: {payload:"world"},
    success: function(response){ alert(response); }
});
```